# Pytorch dataset transform leading to attribute error

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, transform

I'm working with the TUDataset MUTAG in Pytorch. I've created a custom transform which only modifies the data entry if it has data.edgeindex = 'the edge index of the first data entry'. The idea is that this will be a transform which only modifies the first data entry, so I know the transform can do this for later.

I've made the transform class below:

```
class ReplaceDataTransform(object):
  def __call__(self,data):
    if data.edgeindex == torch.tensor(edgeindex list of first data entry):
      print("Transform being done, new edge index is:",torch.tensor([[0,0,1],[1,2,3]]))
      data.edgeindex = torch.tensor([[0,0,1],[1,2,3]])
    
    return data
```

The code below calls the transform and checks the dataset is right:

```
import torch
from torch_geometric.datasets import TUDataset

dataset = TUDataset(root='data/TUDataset', name='MUTAG', transform=ReplaceDataTransform())

print(dataset)

print(f'Number of features: {dataset.num_features}')
further checks...
```

This returns an error in the last code line:

```
AttributeError: 'TUDataset' object has no attribute 'num_features'
```

This is strange because if I run the second code block without the argument 'transform = ReplaceDataTransform()' the code is fine, returning the number of features. But without the transform my dataset object is incorrect.

I'm very certain the TUDataset object should have an attribute 'num_features' because it seems to be present if I run the code without the transform.

Would anyone know why applying a transform is leading to the method no longer being there when it was present before?

edit: I've looked into the code 'in_memory_dataset.py' which is returning the error. Looking through the module, it is true there is no code for a method num_features. However, there is code for a 'num_classes' method. The next line in my second codeblock is:

```
print(f'Number of classes: {dataset.num_classes}')
```

Since the method is present this should be fine, but it returns the same error, saying TUDataset object has no attribute num_classes. This makes it more unusual. I have some questions but will keep with just the one in this question.

edit2: The code now runs fine with the the transform. I made two changes: first, the first code block needed data.edge_index, not data.edgeindex. I guess it makes sense that that was why there was 'no method edge_index'. That was a mistake. Second, and the final change, at line 3 of the first codeblock, the double == sign returns an error in Pytorch,

```
RunTimeError: Boolean value of tensor with more than one value is ambiguous.
```

The solution is to use torch.equal() to test if two tensors are the same. As a result, dataset now *does* have methods num_features and num_classes. I would guess this is because my error of asking the code to run 'data.edgeindex', which is a new method, produced a dataset that was completely new (we're adding a new type of attribute that isn't in MUTAG's dataset). That would make some sense.